# Ratings conflicting with 2 forms

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have created rating system code for 2 forms and when place those 2 forms in a single page, ratings are conflicting with each other. I want to make the rating system work correctly for individual forms when I click on it.

This is the rating system for a single form:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('.ratings_stars').hover(
  // Handles the mouseover
  function() {
    $('.ratings_stars').removeClass('ratings_over');
    $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_over');
  }, function() {
    $('.ratings_stars').removeClass('ratings_over');
  });
});

 $('.ratings_stars').bind('click', function() {
        var star = this;
        $(star).prevAll().removeClass('ratings_over');
        $(star).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_over');
        $(this).next('i').slideToggle('500');
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-star fa-star-o');
        $(star).nextAll().removeClass('ratings_vote');
        $('#client_ratings').val( jQuery(star).attr('data-id') );
        var data_id = jQuery(star).attr('data-id');
        jQuery('.star_' + data_id).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_vote'); 
        $('.ratings_stars').find('i').addClass('fa-star-o').removeClass('fa-star');
        $(this).prevAll().andSelf().find('i').addClass('fa-star').removeClass('fa-star-o'); 
    });
```

```css
.ratings_choice {
    overflow:   visible;
    padding:    10px;
    position:   relative;
    width:      180px;
    height:     32px;
}
.ratings_stars {
    float:      left;
    padding:    2px;
}
.ratings_vote {
    color: green;
}
.ratings_choice {
    font: 10px verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto 40px auto;
    width: 180px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="iva_ratings_choice">
 <div id="r1" class="ratings_choice">
 <a class="star_1 ratings_stars" data-id="1"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
 <a class="star_2 ratings_stars" data-id="2"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
 <a class="star_3 ratings_stars" data-id="3"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
 <a class="star_4 ratings_stars" data-id="4"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
 <a class="star_5 ratings_stars" data-id="5"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
</div></div>

<input type="hidden" name="client_ratings" id="client_ratings">
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way for rating. use Jquery Rateyo plugin
[Jquery RatYo](http://rateyo.fundoocode.ninja/)

go to this link and checkit if any question please ask me

Answer (score 0):

Alter your code so all your elements are selected relative to the cliked/hovered element

```js
 $('.ratings_stars').bind('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('.iva_ratings_choice').next().val( $(this).attr('data-id') );
        $(this).siblings().find('i').addClass('fa-star-o').removeClass('fa-star');
        $(this).prevAll().andSelf().find('i').addClass('fa-star').removeClass('fa-star-o'); 
    });
```

```css
.ratings_choice {
    overflow:   visible;
    padding:    10px;
    position:   relative;
    width:      180px;
    height:     32px;
}
.ratings_stars {
    float:      left;
    padding:    2px;
}
.ratings_choice .fa-star {
    color: green;
}
.ratings_choice {
    font: 10px verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto 40px auto;
    width: 180px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="iva_ratings_choice">
 <div id="r1" class="ratings_choice">
 <a class="star_1 ratings_stars" data-id="1"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
 <a class="star_2 ratings_stars" data-id="2"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
 <a class="star_3 ratings_stars" data-id="3"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
 <a class="star_4 ratings_stars" data-id="4"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
 <a class="star_5 ratings_stars" data-id="5"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
</div></div>

<input type="text" name="client_ratings" id="client_ratings">
<div class="iva_ratings_choice">
 <div id="r1" class="ratings_choice">
 <a class="star_1 ratings_stars" data-id="1"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
 <a class="star_2 ratings_stars" data-id="2"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
 <a class="star_3 ratings_stars" data-id="3"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
 <a class="star_4 ratings_stars" data-id="4"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
 <a class="star_5 ratings_stars" data-id="5"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
</div></div>

<input type="text" name="client_ratings" id="client_ratings">
<div class="iva_ratings_choice">
 <div id="r1" class="ratings_choice">
 <a class="star_1 ratings_stars" data-id="1"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
 <a class="star_2 ratings_stars" data-id="2"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
 <a class="star_3 ratings_stars" data-id="3"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
 <a class="star_4 ratings_stars" data-id="4"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
 <a class="star_5 ratings_stars" data-id="5"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
</div></div>

<input type="text" name="client_ratings" id="client_ratings">
```